# Code review database design for storing college assessments & enrolments

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm desigining a database for a university testing tool – running tests in the cloud, very similar to a CI system.

It needs to store users, courses, enrolments, assessments, submissions & results.

It's not a system powering the entire institution, but it is important for a few different courses. I'd like the database to be well-structured, extensible, and "intuitive" for future maintainers.

**Requirements**:

- Two distinct courses may have the same name (but be run in different years/periods)
- A single course can only be run once per period (of which there are multiple per year)
- Assessment names must be unique *within* a course, but not across other courses.
- A user may be enrolled in a course as an *instructor, tutor, or student*, but not multiple at once. A student may become a tutor for the same course in the future.

I've included my schema below, with relevant comments where I feel they're needed.

```
CREATE TYPE PERIOD          AS ENUM ('summer', 'first', 'autumn', 'winter', 'second', 'spring');
CREATE TYPE ASSESSMENT_TYPE AS ENUM ('assignment', 'lab');
CREATE TYPE TEST_RESULT     AS ENUM ('warnings', 'errors', 'perfect');
CREATE TYPE ROLE            AS ENUM ('student', 'tutor', 'convenor', 'admin');

CREATE TABLE users (
    uid      VARCHAR(20)  PRIMARY KEY,
    email    VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password BYTEA               NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE courses (
    -- id is used instead of (code, period, year) to
    -- uniquely identify a course, since its easier.
    id     SERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    -- code is used within the university to identify a course,
    -- but not when it was run (a single course can be run
    -- multiple times, with different students/assessments/etc)
    code   VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    name   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    period PERIOD       NOT NULL,
    year   INTEGER      NOT NULL,
    -- ensure that a single course can only be run once per period.
    CONSTRAINT once_per_period UNIQUE (code, period, year)
);

CREATE TABLE assessment ( 
    id           SERIAL          PRIMARY KEY,
    name         VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,  
    type         ASSESSMENT_TYPE NOT NULL,
    comments     TEXT,
    course_id    INTEGER         REFERENCES courses(id),
    -- assessment names must be unique within a course,
    -- but not across courses.
    CONSTRAINT unique_name_per_course UNIQUE (name, course_id)
);

CREATE TABLE test_results (
    id            SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY,
    result        TEST_RESULT NOT NULL,
    warnings      TEXT        NOT NULL,
    errors        TEXT        NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE submissions (
    id            SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY,
    title         TEXT        NOT NULL,
    description   TEXT        NOT NULL,
    feedback      TEXT        NOT NULL,
    uid           VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES users(uid),
    assessment_id INTEGER     REFERENCES assessment(id),
    result_id     INTEGER     REFERENCES test_results(id)
);

CREATE TABLE enrol (
    user_uid  VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES users(uid),
    course_id INTEGER     REFERENCES courses(id),
    role      ROLE        NOT NULL,
    -- ensure a user cannot have multiple roles for a single course
    CONSTRAINT one_role_per_course_run UNIQUE (user_uid, course_id)
);
```

I'd like some feedback on my design – what can I do better? Is there anything I missed? Any common/idiomatic design choices?

I was going to post in the [code review stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I saw a previous answer that mentioned this as a better location.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just a few thoughts.

I would not use `ENUM`s. I hate to say **"always"** (open to correction on this) but I would "always" use a `FOREIGN KEY`. Consider gender - 25 years ago, you could have had an `ENUM` ('M', 'F') - now you can have:

- `Unknown`
- `Intersex`
- `Non-binary`
- `Decline-to-answer`
- `Don't know`
- `Don't care` :-)

&c., &c...

With a `FOREIGN KEY` things are far easier to change into the future. Furthermore, you make the point that you want your `database to be well-structured, extensible, and "intuitive" for future maintainers(*)` - `FOREIGN KEY`s will do this by making your system portable to another RDBMS! After an FK, I'd go for a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`!

`(*)` upvoting for this alone! If only all system designers were so thoughtful - some of my  sleepless nights as a programmer might have been avoided! :-)

Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923213/postgres-enum-data-type-or-check-constraint) on SO (both question and accepted answer from the same poster). It tries to go through all options (but misses one - see below!) and the "consensus" (if such a thing can be said to exist on these sites) is, `FK`s, followed by `CC`s. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923213/postgres-enum-data-type-or-check-constraint#comment14351273_10984951) - there's a reason that poster has a rep > 300,000 (not to mention a shedload here too)!

Gotchas. MySQL (**amazingly!**) doesn't support `CK`s! Plus, another factor mitigating against `CC`s is that, frequently, [DBAs and/or sysadmins](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/using-enum-vs-check-constraint-vs-lookup-tables/6704/2) are the only operators allowed to change system tables (which is what modifying `CC`s involves) whereas ordinary programmers/users can change ordinary tables.

A corollary to this is that if you want tight control over disk activity, you might want the smallest possible amount of it on your system tables - every operation involving a `CC` involves querying them, so the overhead of querying the `FK` tables is not such a big deal after all.

A factor in favour of `CC`s over `ENUM`s is that you can use the `LIKE` and other operators on them - you can't with the latter. Finally, take a look at the horrible syntax [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Enum) to compare values in `ENUM`s to other values (remember they're different types!). And if you're doing lookups of values for, say, dropdowns, you'd have to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540711/470530):

```
select n.nspname as enum_schema,  
       t.typname as enum_name,  
       e.enumlabel as enum_value
from pg_type t 
   join pg_enum e on t.oid = e.enumtypid  
   join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
```

as opposed to:

```
select my_field from my_table;
```

All in all, I would strongly urge you to use `FK`s or `CC`s to enforce Declarative Referential Integrity (DRI) on your tables.

There are (mentioned only for completeness) ways of restricting values in tables - you could use [`DOMAIN`](https://www.commandprompt.com/blog/fk_check_enum_or_domain_that_is_the_question/)s or `TRIGGER`s. The former seem [superior](https://www.commandprompt.com/blog/fk_check_enum_or_domain_that_is_the_question/) to `ENUM`s, whereas `TRIGGER`s (IMHO) should only be used for complex business logic!

Finally, to answer the question (phew...).

Your schema **seems** fine - it's pretty difficult to judge these things by eye. What I would do if I were you, is to start using/developing against it and see if you come up against problems. Get back to us here with specific issues if you do - your question is a bit broad! p.s. welcome to the forum!